# Shufflling for Differential Evolutionary Algorithm in CUDA

Tags: cuda

I would like to implement a Differential Evolutionary Algorithm in CUDA.
How can I get two random vectors from matrix, knowing that they cannot be accessed again or, conversely, that they can? Is there an easy way of shuffling vectors in matrices?
I would also need to compute something using values from such a vector, and put new values in the bottom cell of each vector. It is easy to do? How to do it?
Maybe there is something like a stack implementation library (get by id, peek by id, ...)?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should have a look at thrust library, which is sort of a C++ STL equivalent for CUDA. It has been integrated in the latest release of the CUDA toolkit, but if you have an older version of CUDA you can still download it for free at: http://code.google.com/p/thrust/

in this library, you'll find easy ways to handle vectors and to generate random numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning the implementation of the Differential Evolutionary Algorithm in CUDA as proposed in

```
R. Storn and K. Price, "Differential evolution: a simple and efficient heuristic for global optimization over continuous spaces," Journal of Global Optimization, vol. 11, no. 4, pp. 341-359, 1997
```

you seem to be concerned with the crossover operation. The only significant CUDA implementation of the Differential Evolutionary Algorithm in CUDA I'm aware is that in

```
L.P. de Veronese, R.A. Krohling, "Differential evolution algorithm on the GPU with C-CUDA," Proc. of the IEEE Congress on Evolutionary Computation, Barcelona, Spain, July 18-23, 2010, pp. 1-7.
```

Below, I'm showing a full CUDA code based on the implementation suggested in the latter paper.

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/extrema.h>

#include <curand.h>
#include <curand_kernel.h>

using namespace thrust;

#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <fstream>

#include "Utilities.cuh"

#define pi 3.14159265358979f

#define BLOCK_SIZE_POP  32
#define BLOCK_SIZE_RAND 64
#define BLOCK_SIZE_UNKN 8
#define BLOCK_SIZE      256

//#define DEBUG

// --- REFERENCES
//     [1] R. Storn and K. Price, “Differential evolution – a simple and efficient heuristic for global optimization over continuous spaces,” 
//     Journal of Global Optimization, vol. 11, no. 4, pp. 341–359, 1997

//     [2] Lucas de P. Veronese and Renato A. Krohling, “Differential Evolution Algorithm on the GPU with C-CUDA,” 
//     Proc. of the IEEE Congress on Evolutionary Computation, Barcelona, Spain, Jul. 18-23, 2010, pp. 1-7.

// Conventions: the index j addresses the population member while the index i addresses the member component
//              the homologous host and device variables have the same name with a "h_" or "d_" prefix, respectively
//              the __host__ and __device__ functions pointer parameters have the same name for comparison purposes. it is up to the caller to use 
//              host or device pointers, as appropriate

/****************************************/
/* EVALUATION OF THE OBJECTIVE FUNCTION */
/****************************************/
__global__ void curand_setup_kernel(curandState * __restrict state, const unsigned long int seed)
{
    int tid =  blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    curand_init(seed, tid, 0, &state[tid]);
}

/********************************/
/* INITIALIZE POPULATION ON GPU */
/********************************/
__global__ void initialize_population_GPU(float * __restrict pop, const float * __restrict minima, const float * __restrict maxima, 
                                          curandState * __restrict state, const int D, const int Np) {

    int i = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    int j = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;

    if ((i < D) && (j < Np)) pop[j*D+i] = (maxima[i] - minima[i]) * curand_uniform(&state[j*D+i]) + minima[i];
}

/****************************************/
/* EVALUATION OF THE OBJECTIVE FUNCTION */
/****************************************/
__host__ __device__ float functional(const float * __restrict x, const int D) {

    float sum = 0.f;

    // --- De Jong function
    //for (int i=0; i<D; i++) sum = sum + x[i] * x[i];
    // --- Rosenbrock's saddle
    sum = 0.f;
    for (int i=1; i<D; i++) sum = sum + 100.f * (x[i] - x[i-1] * x[i-1]) * (x[i] - x[i-1] * x[i-1]) + (x[i-1] - 1.f) * (x[i-1] - 1.f);

    return sum;
}

/********************************/
/* POPULATION EVALUATION ON GPU */
/********************************/
__global__ void evaluation_GPU(const int Np, const int D, const float * __restrict pop, float * __restrict fobj) {

    int j = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    if (j < Np)  fobj[j] = functional(&pop[j*D], D);
}

/**********************************************************/
/* GENERATE MUTATION INDICES AND CROSS-OVER VALUES ON GPU */
/**********************************************************/
__global__ void generate_mutation_indices_and_crossover_values_GPU(float * __restrict Rand, int * __restrict mutation, const int Np, const int D,
                                                                   curandState * __restrict state) {

    int j = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    int a, b, c;

    if (j < Np) {

        do a=Np*(curand_uniform(&state[j*D]));  while(a==j);
        do b=Np*(curand_uniform(&state[j*D]));  while(b==j||b==a);
        do c=Np*(curand_uniform(&state[j*D]));  while(c==j||c==a||c==b);
        mutation[j*3]=a;
        mutation[j*3+1]=b;
        mutation[j*3+2]=c;

        Rand[j]=curand_uniform(&state[j*D]);
    }
}

/**********************************/
/* GENERATION OF A NEW POPULATION */
/**********************************/
__global__ void generation_new_population_GPU(const float * __restrict pop, const int NP, const int D, float * __restrict npop, const float F, 
                                              const float CR, const float * __restrict rand, const int * __restrict mutation, 
                                              const float * __restrict minimum, const float * __restrict maximum) {

    int i = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    int j = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;

    if ((i < D) && (j < NP)) {

        // --- Mutation indices
        int a=mutation[j*3];
        int b=mutation[j*3+1];
        int c=mutation[j*3+2];

        // --- Mutation and crossover
        // --- One of the best strategies. Try F = 0.7 and CR = 0.5 as a first guess.
        if(rand[j]<CR)  npop[j*D+i] = pop[a*D+i]+F*(pop[b*D+i]-pop[c*D+i]);
        else            npop[j*D+i] = pop[j*D+i];

        // --- Other possible approaches to mutation and crossover
        // --- Not bad, but found several optimization problems where misconvergence occurs.
        //npop[j*D+i] = pop[best_old_gen_ind*D+i] + F*(pop[b*D+i]-pop_old[c*D+i]);
        // --- One of the best strategies. Try F = 0.85 and CR = 1. In case of misconvergence, try to increase NP. If this doesn't help,
        //     play around with all the control variables.
        //npop[j*D+i] = pop[j*D+i] + F*(pop[best_old_gen_ind*D+i] - pop[j*D+i]) + F*(pop[a*D+i]-pop[b*D+i]);
        // --- Powerful strategy worth trying.
        //npop[j*D+i] = pop[best_old_gen_ind*D+i] + (pop[a*D+i]+pop[b*D+i]-pop[c*D+i]-pop[d*D+i])*F;
        // --- Robust optimizer for many functions.
        //npop[j*D+i] = pop[e*D+i] + (pop[a*D+i]+pop[b*D+i]-pop[c*D+i]-pop[d*D+i])*F;

        // --- Saturation due to constraints on the unknown parameters
        if      (npop[j*D+i]>maximum[i])    npop[j*D+i]=maximum[i];
        else if (npop[j*D+i]<minimum[i])    npop[j*D+i]=minimum[i];

    }

}

/*******************************/
/* POPULATION SELECTION ON GPU */
/*******************************/
// Assumption: all the optimization variables are associated to the same thread block
__global__ void selection_and_evaluation_GPU(const int Np, const int D, float * __restrict pop, const float * __restrict npop, float * __restrict fobj) {

    int i = threadIdx.x;
    int j = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;

    if ((i < D) && (j < Np)) {

        float nfobj = functional(&npop[j*D], D);

        float temp = fobj[j];

        if (nfobj < temp) { 
            pop[j*D+i]  = npop[j*D+i];
            fobj[j]     = nfobj;
        }
    }
}

/***********************/
/* FIND MINIMUM ON GPU */
/***********************/
void find_minimum_GPU(const int N, float *t, float * __restrict minval, int * __restrict index) {

    // --- Wrap raw pointer with a device_ptr 
    device_ptr<float> dev_ptr = device_pointer_cast(t);

    // --- Use device_ptr in thrust min_element
    device_ptr<float> min_ptr = thrust::min_element(dev_ptr, dev_ptr + N);

    index[0] = &min_ptr[0] - &dev_ptr[0];

    minval[0] = min_ptr[0];;

}

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main()
{
    // --- Number of individuals in the population (Np >=4 for mutation purposes)
    int         Np      = 80;  
    // --- Dimensionality of each individual (number of unknowns)
    int         D       = 5;
    // --- Mutation factor (0 < F <= 2). Typically chosen in [0.5, 1], see Ref. [1]
    float       F       = 0.7f;
    // --- Maximum number of generations
    int         Gmax    = 2000;
    // --- Crossover constant (0 < CR <= 1)
    float       CR      = 0.4f;

    // --- Mutually different random integer indices selected from {1, 2, … ,Np}
    int *d_mutation,            // --- Device side mutation vector
        *d_best_index,          // --- Device side current optimal member index
        *h_best_index_dev;      // --- Host side current optimal member index of device side

    float *d_pop,               // --- Device side population
    *d_npop,                    // --- Device side new population (trial vectors)
    *d_Rand,                    // --- Device side crossover rand vector (uniformly distributed in (0,1))
    *d_fobj,                    // --- Device side objective function value
    *d_maxima,                  // --- Device side maximum constraints vector
    *d_minima,                  // --- Device side minimum constraints vector
    *h_pop_dev_res,             // --- Host side population result of GPU computations
    *h_best_dev,                // --- Host side population best value history of device side
    *h_maxima,                  // --- Host side maximum constraints vector
    *h_minima;                  // --- Host side minimum constraints vector

    curandState *devState;      // --- Device side random generator state vector

    // --- Device side memory allocations
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_pop,D*Np*sizeof(float)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_npop,D*Np*sizeof(float)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_Rand,Np*sizeof(float)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_fobj,Np*sizeof(float)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_mutation,3*Np*sizeof(int)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_maxima,D*sizeof(float)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_minima,D*sizeof(float)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&devState, D*Np*sizeof(curandState)));

    // --- Host side memory allocations
    h_pop_dev_res       = (float*)malloc(D*Np*sizeof(float));
    h_best_dev          = (float*)malloc(Gmax*sizeof(float));
    h_best_index_dev    = (int*)malloc(Gmax*sizeof(int));
    h_maxima            = (float*)malloc(D*sizeof(float));
    h_minima            = (float*)malloc(D*sizeof(float));

    // --- Define grid sizes
    int Num_Blocks_Pop      = iDivUp(Np,BLOCK_SIZE_POP);
    int Num_Blocks_Rand2    = iDivUp(Np,BLOCK_SIZE_RAND);
    dim3 Grid(iDivUp(D,BLOCK_SIZE_UNKN),iDivUp(Np,BLOCK_SIZE_POP));
    dim3 Block(BLOCK_SIZE_UNKN,BLOCK_SIZE_POP);

    // --- Set maxima and minima
    for (int i=0; i<D; i++) {
        h_maxima[i] =  2.;
        h_minima[i] = -2.;
    }
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_maxima, h_maxima, D*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_minima, h_minima, D*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    // --- Initialize cuRAND states
    curand_setup_kernel<<<iDivUp(D*Np, BLOCK_SIZE), BLOCK_SIZE>>>(devState, time(NULL));

    // --- Initialize popultion
    initialize_population_GPU<<<Grid, Block>>>(d_pop, d_minima, d_maxima, devState, D, Np);
#ifdef DEBUG
    gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
#endif

    // --- Evaluate population
    evaluation_GPU<<<iDivUp(Np, BLOCK_SIZE), BLOCK_SIZE>>>(Np, D, d_pop, d_fobj);
#ifdef DEBUG
    gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
#endif

    int a, b, c;
    for(int i=0;i<Gmax;i++) {

        // --- Generate mutation indices and cross-over uniformly distributed random vector
        generate_mutation_indices_and_crossover_values_GPU<<<Num_Blocks_Rand2,BLOCK_SIZE_RAND>>>(d_Rand, d_mutation, Np, D, devState);
#ifdef DEBUG
        gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
        gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
#endif

        // --- Generate new population
        generation_new_population_GPU<<<Grid,Block>>>(d_pop, Np, D, d_npop, F, CR, d_Rand, d_mutation, d_minima, d_maxima);
#ifdef DEBUG
        gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
        gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
#endif

        // --- Select new population and evaluate it
        selection_and_evaluation_GPU<<<Grid,Block>>>(Np, D, d_pop, d_npop, d_fobj);
#ifdef DEBUG
        gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
        gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
#endif

        find_minimum_GPU(Np, d_fobj, &h_best_dev[i], &h_best_index_dev[i]);

        printf("Iteration: %i; best member value: %f: best member index: %i\n", i, h_best_dev[i], h_best_index_dev[i]);

    }

    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_pop_dev_res, d_pop, Np*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    for (int i=0; i<D; i++) printf("Variable nr. %i = %f\n", i, h_pop_dev_res[h_best_index_dev[Gmax-1]*D+i]);

    return 0;
}
```